#  Example: Nil  radical  of  noetherian  Rings  with  a map  to simple  noetherian  rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

A  basic  example  in  commutative  algebra:  Let  $A$ $B$  be  noetherian rings,  with  $B$  simple  noetherian. Suppose  that    for  every  element $b$ in $B$, there  exists  a power $b^{n}$  belonging  to  the  image of   the  map.  Is  the nilradical  in $A$  trivial ? Can  one say   something  about  prime ideals  in   $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by a simple Noetherian commutative ring? A field? 

Comment: If the kernel of the map is additionally contained in the radical of A, then the map is called a "F-isomorphism". It induces an bijection from Spec(B) on Spec(A). 

Comment: By a simple commutative ring i mean with trivial nilradical. Simon, some reference on this?

Comment: What if $B$ is $A_\text{red} = A/nil(A)$?

Comment: Graham, I actually would like conditions for this to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the nilradical of $A$ isn't trivial. As an example let $B =k$ be a field an $A=k[X]/(X^2)$ be the exterior algebra over $k$. Then $f: A \to k, X \to 0$ is surjective and the radical of $A$ is $(X)$.

Concerning the primes: Let $f:A \to B$ be a homomorphism of rings such that for each $b \in B$ a power of $b$ is in the image of $f$. Then there is an injection 
$$\text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A), P \mapsto f^{-1}(P)$$
Proof: $f$ always induces a mapping between the spectra. So it's enough to show injectivity: Let $P,Q$ be primes of $B$ with $f^{-1}(P) = f^{-1}(Q)$. Let $b \in Q$. There is $n > 0$ and $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b^n \in Q$. In particular, $a \in f^{-1}(Q) = f^{-1}(P)$. Thus $b^n=f(a) \in P$ and since $P$ is prime, $b \in P$. Hence $Q \subseteq P$. By symmetry $P \subseteq Q$ holds as well.